# Angular slides with components

Tags: angular

I want to create slides with animation like [TweenDeck.js](https://github.com/johnpolacek/tweendeck/), but with more *component* style to use it in Angular applications.
The idea I have is to create an abstract class `Slide` that will contain all fields that is required for the animation. Then developers could extend from it and create components. Then in `app.component.html` I will have slides like this:

```
<greeting-slide [intro-animation]="Animations.fadeIn" [outro-animation]="Animations.fadeOut">
    Hello, world!
</greeting-slide>
<simple-slide>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
    </ul>
</simple-slide>
<simple-slide></simple-slide>
<goodbye-slide></goodbye-slide>
```

I've had an idea to fetch all components and then filter them by `instanceof Slide`. Then manipulate with them.

But it seems that there should be a better solution.

How can I achieve this kind of implementation?

Comment: You have XY problem. It's impossible to do what you're trying to do this in Angular, at least in a reasonable way. I'd suggest to explain your case further and provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , so a proper alternative solution could be suggested.

Comment: @estus, I fully edited my question. I provided what I want to achieve and what actions I have tried to take.

Comment: What about Slide class? Usually you need to handle this in reverse, i.e. register component instance in component ngOnInit.